# Recommendations on how to auction a domain name

Tags: domains

We've a domain name that's okay, though hardly brilliant, that we no longer need.

How would you go about auctioning or selling it?  Has someone a recommended site where to put it up?

I'm assuming this is fair practice, we had thought we'd a real use for it and we're certainly not squatting the name.

Comment: When WebMasters SE goes public beta, this would be more appropriate there.

Comment: fair enough, i'll have to wait till then...

Comment: are you happy with one of the answers, @dove? Pick one! You don't have to wait for Webmasters SE if you are happy with one of the answers here.

Comment: @Gaia thanks for nudge, I'd +1 yours ages ago but went with Sedo so   John got there first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sedo](http://sedo.com/us/home/getting-started/?tracked=&partnerid=&language=us) is a good place to start. Some registrars like [Godaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/auctions/domain-auctions.aspx?ci=9054) also have marketplaces.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure you have the rights*, here is the list.

- Snapnames.com
- Sedo.com
- Godaddy.com Auctions
- Auctionpus.com
- Ebay.com
- Latonas.com
- Afternic.com
- Domainmonkey.com
- Bido.com
- Domaintools.com
- Greatdomains.com (Part Of Sedo)
- Namejet.com
- Snapnames.com
- Winyourdomain.com

You can also try to sell it via the specialized forums (incomplete list):

- dnforum.com
- namepros.com
- domainforums.com

Good luck!

PS: Only an IP lawyer can tell you for sure if you have the rights to the domain name and domain name disputes are usually resolved by the [World Intellectual Property Organization](http://www.wipo.int).

While your domain is sitting in your hands, you might as well make some money of it. Park your domain at a [domain monetization service](https://www.google.com/search?pws=0&q=domain%20monetization)